# BaseAdapter and Picasso issue

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter, picasso

I am having a problem loading images in ListView from a server with Picasso.

I have a BaseAdapter that is used to fill my ListView. In this ListView some items have an image and some not.

in this method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

I do:

```
 ...

//context = Activity context;
//context1 = Context context1;
context1 = context.getApplicationContext();

 if (!photo[position].equals("")) {

    String stringurl = "http://www.blablabla.it/img/"+photo[position]+".jpg";

    Picasso.with(context1)
           .load(stringurl)
           .placeholder(R.drawable.white)
           .into(holder.imageD);
        }
 else {

    holder.imageD.setImageBitmap(null);
 }
```

**This code work, but too often I see that an image is in a different place than where it belongs!**

as you can imagine this is very annoying for users .. Thanks everybody

Comment: you should also use Picasso call in else statment ... then any load request for `holder.imageD` should be cancelled ...

Comment: @Selvin so i should write: holder.imageD.setImageBitmap(null); if(...) { Picasso...} ? can you give me an example please?

Comment: `else {Picasso.with(context1)
           .load(null)
           .placeholder(R.drawable.white)
           .into(holder.imageD);}`

Comment: @Selvin write: else{ holder.imageD.setImageBitmap(null); } is not the same thing?

Comment: No! Did you read my comment?

Comment: @Selvin seems the issue is gone! Thanks! if you want to leave a reply I will be happy to accept it

Comment: Ok here you go... with some more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had faced this problem becuase ListView recycle items view + Picasso calls are asynchronous ... How it can appears?

1. You **start** loading with Picasso
2. View is reused (convertView != null)
3. You are setting `holder.imageD.setImageBitmap(null);`
4. Asynchronous from point 1. is finnished

Thats why you are having wrong image loaded ...

To avoid such behaviour you need to inform Picasso loader to cancel previous request.
So instead just setting image bitmap to null you have to set it via Picasso library (in else statment use):

`Picasso.with(context1).load(null).placeholder(R.drawable.white).into(holder.imageD);`

**edit:** following @Budius comments: even better solution will be cancel and set instead like:

```
{
  Picasso.with(context1).cancelRequest(holder.imageD);
  //holder.imageD.setImageBitmap(null); //or
  holder.imageD.setImageResource(R.drawable.white); //depends on your needs
}
```

This should be more efficent way as it should creates less internal objects on every getView calls.

Comment: I believe it's better practice to manually set the null on your image and just inform Picasso to cancel the request `Picasso.with(c).cancelRequest(holder.imageD); holder.imageD.setImageBitmap(null);` Your way seems to be creating a new request for no good reason.

Comment: @Budius ... what do you mean by "new request" ? (Request object from piccasso library or some network request?) in fact it will be almost the same code as in "into" we have: `if (!data.hasImage()) {
      picasso.cancelRequest(target);
      target.onPrepareLoad(setPlaceholder ? getPlaceholderDrawable() : null);
      return;
    }` and if uri is null then hasImage return false ... so there will be no network's operation used(if fact, it will be syncrounus call) ... also with my version there will be placeholder used instead null bitmap

Comment: I meant `new RequestCreator` object from the library. From source line #293 `if (path == null) { return new RequestCreator(this, null, 0);` and the `private void cancelExistingRequest(Object target) ` code on line #569 simply cancels the existing one. I know those are small, but imagine that list scrolling thousands of items and the GC having to run to remove all those tiny objects. Regarding the placeholder: it can just as well call `setImageResource(R....)` on the ImageView (source: https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java )

Comment: ok ... i've added your comments to the answer ... still wonder if placeholder is cached somehow ... and is android framework is caching `setImageResource` ... if answer is yes and no then there is a chance that first version can be more efficent :)